# Filter the polygon on here map using custom JSON data through javascript

Tags: here-api

I need to implement a filter functionality on my custom dataset .
We have CBSA data stored in datahub and we are drawing polygons of this on the map. We have a few filters such as brands and listing type based on which selection we would like to display only relevant CBSAs on the map as polygons.

I'm consuming here api to draw the polygon. and wanted to implement this feature through Javascript.
below is the our data on which we will be using to draw and filter the polygon on map

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
            "cbsaId": 11580,
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "cbsaName": "Arcadia, FL",
                "cbsaId": 11580,
                "@ns:com:here:xyz":{
                "territoryTypes": [
                    {
                        "territoryType": "Available New",
                        "conceptCodes": [
                            {
                                "conceptCode": "WDG",
                                "isPartial": true
                            },
                            {
                                "conceptCode": "SHG",
                                "isPartial": false
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "territoryType": "Existing",
                        "conceptCode": [
                            "MLY",
                            "ASV"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates":  [
                    [
                        [
                            -81.992522,
                            27.0317
                        ],
                        [
                            -81.995837,
                            27.031710999999998
                        ],
                        [
                            -81.992522,
                            27.0317
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },{
            "cbsaId": 14780,
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "cbsaName": "Brenham, TX",
                "cbsaId": 14780,
                "@ns:com:here:xyz":{
                "territoryTypes": [
                    {
                        "territoryType": "Available Established",
                        "conceptCodes": [
                            {
                                "conceptCode": "MDG",
                                "franchisedetails": {
                                    "franchiseId": 0,
                                    "franchiseWebLocationId": 0,
                                    "dbaName": "string",
                                    "address": "string",
                                    "address2": "string",
                                    "city": "string",
                                    "stateAbbr": "string",
                                    "postalCode": "string",
                                    "distanceMiles": 0,
                                    "isAvailableForSale": true
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "conceptCode": "GUY",
                                "franchisedetails": {
                                    "franchiseId": 0,
                                    "franchiseWebLocationId": 0,
                                    "dbaName": "string",
                                    "address": "string",
                                    "address2": "string",
                                    "city": "string",
                                    "stateAbbr": "string",
                                    "postalCode": "string",
                                    "distanceMiles": 0,
                                    "isAvailableForSale": false
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "territoryType": "Existing",
                        "conceptCode": [
                            "MDG",
                            "GUY"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [-96.62198, 30.044283],
                        [-96.288772, 30.370065999999998],
                        [-96.289191, 30.371485],
                        [-96.62198, 30.044283]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }]
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about the request of filtering JSON data. Filtering JSON data in Javascript please see following article. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401582/filter-the-polygon-on-here-map-using-custom-json-data-through-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below example,which how we can filter json data in javascript.

```js
var yahoo = [], j = `[{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}]`

var data = JSON.parse(j, function(key, value) { 
      if ( value.website === "yahoo" ) yahoo.push(value); 
      return value; })

console.log( yahoo )
```